# Storing Google Translate results

Tags: google-translation-api

My client is using Google Translate API to translate text from English to multiple languages. If the client provides me original and translated text in the form of say Excel sheet, am I allowed to store the translated text in my database?
I tried googling this and found a page which says its not allowed, so wanted to confirm on that. Ref: [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/arzNr0QSNww)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Translation API FAQ document](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#attribution) if you're post-editing the results, there's no attribution required, however, if you're publishing the results of the translation, then, according to the [Attribution Requirements](https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution#overview), you must make it clear that they're viewing an automatic translation from Google Translate. Additionally, keep in mind that the discussion link that you provided is from 2011 and it information might be outdated.