# Can we store Google Translated Content in our Database for further usage?

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

We are  using Google Translate API to translate text  to multiple languages.  We are planing to store in cache services for further usages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Google Translate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400574/storing-google-translate-results)

Answer (score 0):

You can technically do this, but you might not be allowed to.

[You can cache translations for up to 15 days](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/arzNr0QSNww) as long as the user initiated the translation request. So you can't just cache these yourself on your server, but need to have someone visit the site first that initiates the request.

Comment: The discussion thread is from 2011, the current ToS of Google Translation API seem to have no restrictions regarding storage of the translated data (Google itself will delete the translated data after processing) - https://cloud.google.com/translate/data-usage

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can, you need to use "language/translate/v2" to use the API translation. You can also use "translate/v2/detect" so google can detect the type of language to translate. Hope it helps.